# Vector Space and Linear Map

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $V = \mathbb{Q^{n}}$ and $W = \mathbb{Q^n}$ be vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$. Suppose that $f: V \to W$ satisfies $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$ for all $x, y \in V$ . Prove that $f$ is a linear map.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Then for all $l \in \mathbb N$ and $x \in V$ $f(l x) = l f(x)$, $f(-lx)= -l f(x)$. And if $l \neq 0$ $f(\frac{1}{l} x) = \frac{1}{l} f(x)$.

Conclude as any rational $\lambda$ can be written $\lambda = \frac{p}{q}$ where $p \in \mathbb Z$ and $q \in \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

To show linearity, it only remains to show that $f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x)$ for any \lambda\in\Bbb Q$.

1.- For $n\in\Bbb N$, by induction it is easy to show that $f(nx)=nf(x)$:

- $n=1$ is trivial.
- $n\to n+1$: $f((n+1)x)=f(nx+x)=f(nx)+f(x)\overset{HI}{=}nf(x)+f(x)=(n+1)f(x)$.

2.- For $n\in\Bbb N$ it holds that $f(x/n)=f(x)/n$. Indeed, $f(x)=f(n\cdot (x/n))=nf(x/n)$.

3.- Finally, $f(-x)=-f(x)$: $0=f(0)=f(x+(-x))=f(x)+f(-x)$, so $f(-x)=-f(x)$. (Observe that this, togeteher with 1, we get that $f(nx)=nf(x)$ for any $n\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}$, but the case $n=0$ still holds).

Putting altogether, for any $\lambda\in\Bbb Q$, $\lambda=\frac{m}{n}$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$ and $m\in\Bbb Z$. So $f(\lambda x)=f(mx/n)=mf(x/n)=(n/m)f(x)=\lambda f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)\Rightarrow f(0)=0\Rightarrow f(0x)=f(0)=0=0f(x)$.

$f(-x)=f(-x+(-x)+x)=f(-x)+f(-x+x)=f(-x)+f(-x)+f(x)\Rightarrow f(-x)=-f(x)$

Let $n\in\Bbb N$. Then (using induction) $f(nx)=f(x+x+\ldots+x)=f(x)+f(x+\ldots+x)=\ldots=f(x)+f(x)+\ldots+f(x)=nf(x)$.

Also $f(-nx)=f(-x+(-x)+\ldots+(-x))=f(-x)+f(-x)+\ldots+f(-x)=-f(x)+-f(x)+\ldots+-f(x)=-nf(x)$

Finally, for $\frac{p}{q}\in \Bbb Q\setminus\{0\}$, we have $pf(x)=f(px)=f(q\frac{p}{q}x)=qf(\frac{p}{q}x)\Rightarrow f(\frac{p}{q}x)=\frac{p}{q}f(x)$

Comment: Does this answer your question?